# Is there a way to tell in runtime if a class property comes from an interface?

Tags: c#

```
public class Bus : IPresentable
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Bus";
    public int ID { get; set; } = 12345;

    //******** IPresentable interface ***************//
    public int LocX { get; set; }

    public int LocY { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IPresentable
{
    int LocX { get; set; }
    int LocY { get; set; }
}
```

in my application:

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
bus.LocX = 10; // is there a way to tell that this comes from interface
bus.Name = "New Name" ; // but this is not ?
```

Comment: Properties don't "come from" an interface in the way they do from a base class. An interface is just a contract. When a class implements an interface, it's just saying "I agree to meet this interface's contract requirements". So you know `Bus` has a `LocX` property. Are you just trying to determine if `Bus` implements `IPresentable`? If so, you just need to check `typeof(IPresentable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Bus))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using reflection, we can interrogate the `Bus` class and retrieve the list of property names that "belong" both to the class and all interfaces it might be implementing:

```
var interfaceProperties = typeof(Bus)
    .GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name)
    .Intersect(typeof(Bus)
        .GetInterfaces()
        .SelectMany(i => i.GetProperties())
        .Select(p => p.Name))
```

The result `interfaceProperties` is an `IEnumerable<string>`. In this case, it would contain:

```
LocX
LocY
```

You can check the list for the properties you want.

IMO, this is an expensive way to interrogate your classes for this information. Maybe with more background about *why* you want to do this, a better alternative could be produced.

Comment: Thats good, but I am actually looking for the opposite, I want to strip out the interface properties and only call the non interface properties.

Comment: @Pacman: Then you would just change `.Intersect()` to `.Except()`, which would produce `ID` and `Name` as results.

Comment: You may also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285392/matching-an-interfaces-properyinfo-with-a-classs-propertyinfo for proper interface - to method mapping (i.e. interface may have just get, but class both get/set).